# Windows 11 Laptop isn't charging on my Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5i

Tags: lenovo-laptop, charging, windows-11

Windows 11 Laptop isn't charging on my Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5i even though I connected it with my given charger. I connected it through USB-c but it is not working. Windows started giving me notifications that this pc isn't charging.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Windows 11 Laptop". Do you mean that you installed Windows 11 on your Lenovo Flex 5i laptop, and that it is now not charging? Did the charging issues begin immediately after you installed Windows 11, did the predate that installation, or was Windows 11 working fine for a bit and then the charging issue began?

Answer (score 0):

Since your machine is recently acquired, it is likely covered by warranty. You can seek help from the retailer,  if they are unhelpful then you can ask the Lenovo warranty support team.

Try this first:

- Power it off, unplug everything,  remove the battery, wait a minute, put the battery back in, and plug it back in and boot it up

---

If that doesn't work you can follow a procedure I found on the Lenovo forum:

Try to uninstall-reinstall battery drivers from Device Manager:

- Access Device Manager. You can go by pressing Windows Key + X, then select Device Manager.
- Click the Batteries section in the Device Manager window.
- Go ahead and right-click the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery and choose Uninstall from the menu.
- Click on Uninstall to confirm.
- Restart the device and the Windows itself will install the generic driver type for the battery to be installed.
- Check if battery can exceed the percentage reported.

Try to generate a battery report as well:

- The following are steps in order to generate/initiate a Battery Report in Windows.
- Right-click on the Windows Icon in the bottom-left corner of desktop and select "Search".
- Launch the command prompt, by typing "cmd" into the search bar, right-click the program showing up and then choose "Run as Administrator".
- Put these in the blinking curse: "powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\battery_report.html" into the command prompt window. Exclude the 1st and 3rd quotations.
- Using Explorer navigate to C:\ aka the root directory. You should see a file labeled battery_report.html.

If same issue persist, please try to perform a static drain and load the BIOS to defaults:

Perform a static discharge/power cycle

- Make sure there is still remaining battery power, able to power up the machine.
- Disconnect all cables and/or peripheral devices connected to the machine (ex. power cable, hdmi cable, external mouse/keyboard, flashdrives, etc).
- Ensure that device is powered/switched off.
- Press and hold down the power button for as long as 60 seconds to drain flea power or excess voltage.

Perform/load BIOS defaults

- Make sure that the machine is properly powered down/switched off.
- Find the Novo Button. How a Novo button should look like: https://support.lenovo.com/us/fr/solutions/ht062552
- Access/click this by using an unfolded paperclip or by using something similar to the latter.
- Machine will power up to Novo Menu. Navigate and select using the arrow keys to BIOS Set Up.
- Inside the BIOS Set Up, navigate to the Exit Menu. Select Load Setup Default - click Enter, select YES and click Enter.
- Select Exit and Save Changes then click Enter, select YES and click Enter.
- The computer will start up.

Credits: Dex_Lenovo, support specialist at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/Battery-not-charging-Lenovo-Flex-5/m-p/5080177